# jquery mouseenter proper implrmentation?

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I have a navigation menu where in menu "hotels", a slide down panel is implemented.
This is the script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".HotelPaneltrigger").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".panel").slideDown("slow");
        //$(this).toggleClass("active"); return false; 
    });

    $(".panel").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).slideUp("slow");
    }); 
});
```

Now, i have 2 problems:
.HotelPaneltrigger fires the panel (.panel) to slide down
the panel slides up as soon mouse leaves the .panel area

1st problem: hovering between my "HotelPaneltrigger" & ".panel" will result that the panel slides up and down multiple times, as both functions are executed as long user hovers between both elements.

2nd problem: panel is defined to slide up as soon user leaves ".panel" area

What solution to you recommend to:
slide down panel on "HotelPaneltrigger" and stay open as long user is in "HotelPaneltrigger" + ".panel" area.. and closes when hovering away from them?

I need to avoid multiple slide up and down of panel, while closing it when user moves away from the triggering link... not the .panel area

Your input is appreciated

The menu code i use:

```
        <ul class="primary_nav">  

                <li class="active"><a href="link to.php" class="hoverBtn">Link 1</a></li>
                <li class="HotelPaneltrigger"><a href="#" class="hoverBtn">Hotels</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="hoverBtn">Link 3</a>
                    <ul class="subnav">  
                        <li><a href="link to.php">Link 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="link to.php">Link 5</a></li>
                    </ul>           
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="hoverBtn">Link 6</a>
                    <ul class="subnav">  
                        <li><a href="link to.php">Sub 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="link to.php">Sub 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="link to.php">Sub 3</a></li>        
                    </ul>
                </li>               

                <li class="last"><a href="link to.php" class="hoverBtn">Specials</a></li>           
        </ul>
```

Comment: is it possible to create a jsfiddle for this? I'm having a hard time visualizing the problem as you're describing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xmtpu/

Basically since its for a menu you put the panel inside the trigger and put both event handlers on the trigger. Because the panel is a child you are still "entering" on the tirgger even when your mouse is over the panel.

Comment: That is exactly what i need prodigitalson :-) But still confused as i have a menu script in wich i have my hotels link embeded. See above

Comment: it tried implementing in my existing navigation menu, under <li class="HotelPaneltrigger"><a href="#" class="hoverBtn">Hotels <<panel here>> </a></li>, but panel won't show up. will check again if it's a css issue

Comment: it most likely is. in this case you actually want the trigger element to be the `li` not the `a`. Ill try and to a revised fiddle when i have time if you havent figured it out by then :-)

Comment: I did a fiddle to test with my running navigation menu including your function as well. Either functions conflict or.. it's me :-) Here is the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/pivi/PJjCy/15/

Comment: well, you won't believe what the issue was: i used your class="hotelPanelTrigger" which is different from mine calss="HotelPaneltrigger"... that cuased that panel was not triggered. Now your solution works like a charm :-) ..how do i extend the function with a delay after panel was closed, to avoid the multiple up/down effect again?

Comment: Just use the `hoverIntent` plugin... youll save yourself time and headaches :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this;

```
$('.HotelPaneltrigger').hover(
    function () {
        // Show hidden content IF it is not already showing
        if($('.panel').css('display') == 'none') {
            $('.panel').slideDown('slow');
        }
    },
    function () {
        // Do nothing when mouse leaves HotelPaneltrigger
        $.noop();
    }
);

$('.panel').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).delay('500').slideUp('slow');
});
```

You could also try the hoverIntent plugin if this doesn't work completely - http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: your solution brings it a bit closer, the delay helps to prevent multiple triggering.. but the panel still closes only when mouseleave the panel.

Comment: Try the hoverIntent plugin, add that and then change the .hover function to .hoverIntent